# Read a file line by line and if condition is met continue reading till next condition

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, read

I have  a file foo.txt

```
test
qwe
asd
xca
asdfarrf
sxcad
asdfa
sdca
dac
dacqa
ea
sdcv
asgfa
sdcv
ewq
qwe
a
df
fa
vas
fg
fasdf
eqw
qwe
aefawasd
adfae
asdfwe
asdf
era
fbn
tsgnjd
nuydid
hyhnydf
gby
asfga
dsg
eqw
qwe
rtargt
raga
adfgasgaa
asgarhsdtj
shyjuysy
sdgh
jstht
ewq
sdtjstsa
sdghysdmks
aadfbgns,
asfhytewat
bafg
q4t
qwe
asfdg5ab
fgshtsadtyh
wafbvg
nasfga
ghafg
ewq
qwe
afghta
asg56ang
adfg643
5aasdfgr5
asdfg
fdagh5t
ewq
```

I want to print all the lines between `qwe` and `ewq` in a separate file.
This is what I have so far :

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="foo.txt"

#While loop to read line by line
while read -r line
do
    readLine=$line
    #If the line starts with ST then echo the line
    if [[ $readLine = qwe* ]] ; then
        echo "$readLine"
        read line
        readLine=$line
        if [[ $readLine = ewq* ]] ; then
            echo "$readLine"
        fi
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

Comment: `sed '/qwe/,/ewq/ w other.file' foo.txt`

Comment: @Costas I cant use that because I need to do some logic between these lines . .

Comment: Sure you can... If you're using `while..read` you're almost always doing it wrong.

Comment: @don_crissti what do you mean ?

Comment: @don_crissti well I just wanted to know why `while .. read` is wrong ?

Comment: [read this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @don_crissti And the solution to such problem is?

Comment: @BinaryZebra - what problem ? If you know what the real problem is here please explain it so that we can understand it because the question is (obviously) some sort of _XY_ question but the OP doesn't even bother explaining what _X_ is (the real problem).

Comment: @don_crissti The problem **you** introduce in [read this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716). Sure there there is no indication of a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your script (in no particular order):

- Use `IFS=` before `read` to avoid removing leading and trailing spaces.
- As `$line` is not changed anywhere, there is no need for variable `readLine`.
- Do not use read in the middle of the loop!!.
- Use a Boolean variable to control printing.
- Make clear the start and end of printing.

With those changes, the script becomes:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="foo.txt"

#While loop to read line by line
while IFS= read -r line; do
    #If the line starts with ST then set var to yes.
    if [[ $line == qwe* ]] ; then
        printline="yes"
        # Just t make each line start very clear, remove in use.
        echo "----------------------->>"
    fi
    # If variable is yes, print the line.
    if [[ $printline == "yes" ]] ; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
    #If the line starts with ST then set var to no.
    if [[ $line == ewq* ]] ; then
        printline="no"
        # Just to make each line end very clear, remove in use.
        echo "----------------------------<<"
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

Which could be condensed in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="foo.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line == qwe* ]]       && printline="yes"
    [[ $printline == "yes" ]] && echo "$line"
    [[ $line == ewq* ]]       && printline="no"
done < "$filename"
```

That will print the start and end lines (inclusive).
If there is no need to print them, swap the start and end tests:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="foo.txt"
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line == ewq* ]]       && printline="no"
    [[ $printline == "yes" ]] && echo "$line"
    [[ $line == qwe* ]]       && printline="yes"
done < "$filename"
```

---

However, it would be quite better (if you have bash version 4.0 or better) to use `readarray` and loop with the array elements:

```
#!/bin/dash
filename="infile"

readarray -t lines < "$filename"


for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    [[ $line == ewq* ]]       && printline="no"
    [[ $printline == "yes" ]] && echo "$line"
    [[ $line == qwe* ]]       && printline="yes"
done
```

That will avoid most of the issues of using `read`.

---

Of course, you could use the recommended (in comments; Thanks, @costas) `sed` line to get only the lines to be processed:

```
    #!/bin/bash
filename="foo.txt"

readarray -t lines <<< "$(sed -n '/^qwe.*/,/^ewq.*/p' "$filename")"

for line in "${lines[@]}"; do

     : # Do all your additional processing here, with a clean input.

done
```

Comment: This answer very nicely answers the question of "how do I cope with most of the issues of using read". Sometimes though, the OP needs to be unasked: using read for this task requires all your explanation and is manifestly the wrong tool for the job when half-line sed comment just works. (±0 if it matters).

Comment: @mikeserv BinaryZebra, please stop having this sort of discussion in the comment threads. Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34538/discussion-on-answer-by-binaryzebra-read-a-file-line-by-line-and-if-condition-is).

Answer (score 5):

As @Costas pointed out, the correct tool to use for this job is `sed`:

```
sed '/qwe/,/ewq/ w other.file' foo.txt
```

There may be other processing needed on the lines to be printed.  That's fine; just do it like so:

```
sed -e '/qwe/,/ewq/{w other.file' -e 'other processing;}' foo.txt
```

(Of course, "other processing" isn't a real `sed` command.)  The above is the pattern to use if you need to do your processing *after* you print the line.  If you want to do some other processing and then print a changed version of the line (which seems more likely), you would use:

```
sed -e '/qwe/,/ewq/{processing;w other.file' -e '}' foo.txt
```

(Note that it is necessary to put the `}` into its own argument, otherwise it will be interpreted as part of the `other.file` name.)

---

You (the OP) haven't stated what "other processing" you have to do on the lines, or I could be more specific.  But whatever that processing is, you can definitely do it in `sed`—or if that becomes too unwieldy, you could do it in `awk` with very little change to the above code:

```
awk '/qwe/,/ewq/ { print > "other.file" }' foo.txt
```

Then, you have all the power of the `awk` programming language at your disposal to do processing on the lines before you execute that `print` statement.  And of course `awk` (and `sed`) are *designed* for text processing, unlike `bash`.

Comment: The solutions do not provide a way for the OP to "I need to do some logic between these lines" *in shell*. Yes, sed or awk may probably do the same (unknown) processing.

Comment: @BinaryZebra, see the last sentence of my answer.  He didn't say he needs to do the logic *in shell*, just that he needs to do some logic.  But it's good that your answer provided a way he can do the logic in shell if he needs to.

Answer (score 1):

```
qwe(){ printf %s\\n "$1"; }
ewq(){ :; }
IFS=   ### prep  the  loop, only IFS= once
while  read -r  in
do     case $in in
       (qwe|ewq)
           set "$in"
       ;;
       ("$processing"?)
           "$process"
       esac
       "$1" "$in"
done
```

That's one really slow way to do it. With a GNU `grep` and a regular *`infile`*:

```
IFS=
while grep  -xm1 qwe
do    while read  -r  in  &&
            [ ewq != "$in" ]
      do    printf %s\\n "$in"
            : some processing
      done
done <infile
```

...would at least optimize out half of the inefficient reads...

```
sed  -ne '/^qwe$/,/^ewq$/H;$!{/^qwe$/!d;}' \
      -e "x;s/'"'/&\\&&/g;s/\n/'"' '/g"    \
      -e "s/\(.*\) .e.*/p '\1/p" <input    |
sh    -c 'p(){  printf %s\\n "$@"
                for l do : process "$l"
                done
          }; . /dev/fd/0'
```

And that would avoid the inefficiencies of `read` altogether for most `sh`'s out there, though it does have to print the output twice - once quoted to `sh` and once unquoted to stdout. It works differently because the `.` command tends to read input by block rather than by byte for most implementations. Still, it elides ewq - qwe altogether, and would work for streamed input - such as a FIFO.

```
qwe
asd
xca
asdfarrf
sxcad
asdfa
sdca
dac
dacqa
ea
sdcv
asgfa
sdcv
qwe
a
df
fa
vas
fg
fasdf
qwe
aefawasd
adfae
asdfwe
asdf
era
fbn
tsgnjd
nuydid
hyhnydf
gby
asfga
dsg
qwe
rtargt
raga
adfgasgaa
asgarhsdtj
shyjuysy
sdgh
jstht
qwe
asfdg5ab
fgshtsadtyh
wafbvg
nasfga
ghafg
qwe
afghta
asg56ang
adfg643
5aasdfgr5
asdfg
fdagh5t
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed '/./=' input2.file | sed -n '/./N;s/\n/  /; /qwe/,/ewq/p'
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is how to *number* lines and then print them using Sed.  That's not what was asked.